# Asp.net core MVC two lists, same model, same controller, two partial views with same model issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have two razor page partial views inside of another view. Both are using the same model.

What I'm doing now after a query is:

```
// get tour data to list to render in _TourenAngebotenPartial.cshtml
                var queryfortourangeboten = from TourAngeboten in _context.TourAngeboten
                                            where TourAngeboten.IdUser == Convert.ToInt32(userid)
                                            select TourAngeboten;

                View(await queryfortourangeboten.ToListAsync());
```

This is working fine. Now I have a similar query creating another list but using the same model.

let's say:                 `List<MTO.TourAngeboten> tourteilgenommenlist = new List<MTO.TourAngeboten>();`

How can I set this as the data source for the other partial called `_TourenTeilgenommenPartial.cshtml`

Is there some parameter I can call with View?
Something maybe like:

```
View("_TourenTeilgenommenPartial", tourteilgenommenlist);
```

I'm calling both partials with:

```
 @await Html.PartialAsync("_TourenAngebotenPartial", Model.TourAngeboten)
```

Comment: How are you calling the partial in the view? (using `@Html.Partial()` or `@Html.Action()`?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke just added to my question. thx

Comment: `Html.PartialAsync` does not call a server method. You would need to use a view component. Alternatively use a view model with 2 `List<MTO.TourAngeboten>` properties

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into view components if there is no other way

Comment: Any code would be appreciated

Comment: The easiest solution is just to have a view model with 2 List<MTO.TourAngeboten> properties, and populate each one with the relevant data in your get method and then use `Html.PartialAsync("_TourenAngebotenPartial", Model.someProperty)` and `Html.PartialAsync("_TourenAngebotenPartial", Model.otherProperty)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This eventually was a perfect case for ViewComponents. I found many websites explaining those but for a change the one from microsoft was the best:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1